# Subclassing argparse.ArgumentParser is producing weird behaviour

Tags: python, argparse

I'm subclassing ArgumentParser so that I can DRY up the common code I have across multiple commands in my package. However, I'm running into some weird behaviour which I'm not able to explain.

See this very simplified version of my program and note the two lines with comments at the end:

```
class Parser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._add_common_args() # (1)

    def _add_common_args(self):
        self.add_argument('-s', '--stage', required=True, type=str.lower)

    def parse(self):
        return self.parse_args(['--stage', 'alpha', 'list-services'])

parser = Parser(prog='my_prog')
# parser._add_common_args() # (2)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='resource')
subparsers.required = True

services_parser = subparsers.add_parser('list-services')

parser.parse()
```

If I run this, the program returns

```
usage: my_prog list-services [-h] -s STAGE
my_prog list-services: error: the following arguments are required: -s/--stage
```

But, if I comment out the line at `(1)` and uncomment the line at `(2)`, it works as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: First things - `parser` without subparsers behaves as expected.  `-s` is required.  Now what happens with subparsers?

Comment: Look at `services_parser`.  It's class is your `Parser`, which means it too expects a '-s'.  And when both '-s' are provided, the subparser value is the one that sticks.

Comment: Use `subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='resource', parser_class=argparse.ArgumentParser)` if you don't want the subparser to get this '-s' argument.

Comment: I ran your code in an interactive session, and looked the parsers etc individually.  I also tested them step by step.  That's called debugging!  Also look at the error message: `my_prog list-services` - that's tells us where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

I used pdb to interact with the code at different breakpoints. And I saw that `services_parser` was a `Parser` instance, but I'm still not able to work out the difference in behaviour between calling `_add_common_args()` from inside `__init__()` and from calling it in the script itself.

Comment: Do you want the subparser, `services_parser` to require a '-s' argument or not?  You are already requiring it for the main.  The subparser parses its own arguments; it doesn't "inherit" any from the main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [3]: parser.print_help()
usage: my_prog [-h] -s STAGE {list-services} ...

positional arguments:
  {list-services}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s STAGE, --stage STAGE
```

Look at the help for `services_parser`:

```
In [4]: services_parser.print_help()
usage: my_prog list-services [-h] -s STAGE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s STAGE, --stage STAGE
```

Both parsers where created using the custom `Parser` class.  When that class adds the '-s' as part of creation, both get that action:

```
In [5]: type(parser)
Out[5]: __main__.Parser
In [6]: type(services_parser)
Out[6]: __main__.Parser
```

So you have to provide that argument in both - but the second overwrites the first:

```
In [7]: parser.parse_args('-s foo list-services -s other'.split())
Out[7]: Namespace(resource='list-services', stage='other')
```

In general using the same argument (with same `dest`) in both is a bad idea.  The subparser value (even the default) dominates.

Your version (2) only sets '-s' on the main.

If I specify an alternative `parser_class`, only the main parser gets the '-s':

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='resource', 
     parser_class=argparse.ArgumentParser)

In [9]: type(services_parser)
Out[9]: argparse.ArgumentParser
In [12]: parser.parse()
Out[12]: Namespace(resource='list-services', stage='alpha')
```

Alternatively you could make the main parser the regular class, and the subparsers the custom one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really interesting that the default parser changes to the custom parser rather than that being something you'd have to explicitly specify

Comment: The defaults are documented for the `add_subparsers` method.  `ArgumentParser` subclassing is usually used to change something more fundamental, like a method.  In such a case expecting the subparsers to behave the same is reasonable.  But keep in mind the `add_parser` does not apply any of the main parser parameters to the sub.  Things like a custom formatter class have to be specified.